# ¿Como pasar contenido variable de un Activity a un Dialog?

Tags: android-studio, activity, alertdialog

tengo una clase `MainActivity` y otra clase Dialogo que extiende de `Dialog`.
Quiero pasar el valor de unas variables de la clase `MainActivity` a la clase Dialogo pero me es imposible.

Alguien tiene alguna información de como se debe hacer esto?Busque e intente cosas pero no consigo pasar el valor de una variable de una clase a otra.

Mi clase `MainActivity` es esta:

```
package com.example.lista.Interface;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

 import com.example.lista.R;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.lang.String;
 import retrofit2.Call;
 import retrofit2.Callback;
 import retrofit2.Response;
 import retrofit2.Retrofit;
 import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Context contexto;
String totales;
ListView list;
EditText dateText;
TextView texto;
ImageView image1;
List<List<List<List<Object>>>> OtroArrayVacio  = new ArrayList<List<List<List<Object>>>>();
List<List<List<List<Object>>>> titles  = new ArrayList<List<List<List<Object>>>>();
List<List<List<List<Object>>>> titlesCopia  = new ArrayList<List<List<List<Object>>>>();
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapterNuevo;
ArrayAdapter adaptador;
String usuario = new String("telecom");
String clave = new String("il0v3t3l3c0m@n");
String error = new String("Algo ha fallado");
Integer sumaDeAlarmas = 0;

Integer tamañoArray =0;
Integer tamañoArray2;
Integer Numero = 0;
Integer contador=0;
List<String> Avisos = new ArrayList<String>();
String date_n = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
String credenciales =  usuario + ":" + clave ;;
String credencialesEnBase64 = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credenciales.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
Integer cont=0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = findViewById(R.id.list);
    contexto = this;
    adaptador = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Avisos);
    list.setAdapter(adaptador);
    getPosts();
    PedirAlarmas();
}

public Integer RecogerPasoPost(){

    return cont=cont+1;
}

public void ActualizarLista(){

    ArrayList OtraLista = new ArrayList(Avisos);

    Avisos.clear();
    adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
    adaptador.addAll(OtraLista);
    adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void PedirAlarmas(){
    final Handler handler= new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sumaDeAlarmas=0;


         //  CerrarAlertDialog.


            getPosts();//llamamos nuestro metodo


     Integer contador=0;
             contador=contador+1;
            handler.postDelayed(this,15000);//se ejecutara cada 10 segundos

        }
    },10000);//empezara a ejecutarse después de 5 milisegundos
}

private void getPosts() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            //.baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.249:9096/datasnap/rest/TMetodosREST/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    PostService postService = retrofit.create(PostService.class);
    Call<Post> call = postService.getPost(credencialesEnBase64);

   RecogerPasoPost();

            call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
                    Post post = (Post) response.body();

                    titles.add(post.getResult());
                    tamañoArray = titles.size();
                    titlesCopia = titles;   //copuia
                    String title1 = titlesCopia.get(0).get(0).get(0).get(0).toString();
                    double title2 = Double.parseDouble(title1);
                    int titles3 = (int) title2;
                    title1 = String.valueOf(titles3);

                    Avisos.clear();

                                      for (int i = 0; i < titlesCopia.get(0).get(0).size(); i++) {
                                          int l = i;
                                          String codigo =  titlesCopia.get(0).get(0).get(i).get(0).toString();
                                          String cadena1 = titlesCopia.get(0).get(0).get(i).get(1).toString();
                                          String codigo2 = titlesCopia.get(0).get(0).get(i).get(2).toString();
                                          String cadena2 = titlesCopia.get(0).get(0).get(i).get(3).toString();
                                          String codigo3 = titlesCopia.get(0).get(0).get(i).get(4).toString();
                                          String codigo4 = titlesCopia.get(0).get(0).get(i).get(5).toString();

                                          totales = codigo + cadena1 + codigo2 + cadena2 + codigo3 + codigo4;

                                          Avisos.add(totales);
                                          Double totalAlarmas = Double.parseDouble(codigo4);
                                          int totalAlarmas1 = (int) totalAlarmas.doubleValue();
                                          contador=contador+1;

                                          if (totalAlarmas1 == 1) {
                                              sumaDeAlarmas = sumaDeAlarmas + 1;
                               //             ConfirmacionAlarma pedro  =new ConfirmacionAlarma(contexto);//(contexto,
                                                  //  totales,sumaDeAlarmas,titlesCopia,Avisos);
                                 //           pedro.ConfirmacionAlarma(contexto);//contexto,
                                                    //totales,sumaDeAlarmas,titlesCopia,Avisos);
                                              AlarmaDialogo Nuevo=new AlarmaDialogo(contexto,totales,sumaDeAlarmas);
                                              Nuevo.show();
                                         //     Intent pasarDatos = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AlarmaDialogo.class);
                                         //     pasarDatos.putExtra("PasarMasDatos","Hola caracola");
                                         //     startActivity(pasarDatos);
                                          }
                                      }

                    adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }


                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", t.getMessage());
                }
            });            }
```

Y la clase Dialogo es esta :

```
package com.example.lista.Interface;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.lista.R;

import java.util.Objects;

public class AlarmaDialogo extends Dialog implements
    android.view.View.OnClickListener {

Bundle Datos;
public Button visto;


public AlarmaDialogo( Context context,String totales, Integer sumaDeAlarmas) {
    super(context);
    String NumeroAvisos= totales;


}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setCancelable(false);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    setContentView(R.layout.dialogo_alarma);


    visto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Aceptar);
    visto.setOnClickListener(this);

    final TextView notiAlarm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notificacionAlarma);

    TextView descAlarm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DescAlarma);

    final TextView contAla = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ContadorAlarmas);

    EditText fechaAlar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Fecha);

    ImageView camapana = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);

    final Button ConfirmarAviso = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Aceptar);


 //   descAlarm.setText(AlarmaDialogo.super);
 //   contAla.setText(String.valueOf(sumaDeAlarmas));
     MainActivity pedro = new MainActivity();
     descAlarm.setText(pedro.totales);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    dismiss();
}
```

Quiero poder acceder al estado de las variables del MainActivity para cuando muestre el Dialog poder pasarle esos valores,intente de todo,si alguien tiene alguna idea se lo agradeceria.

Comment: No termino de entender bien lo que quieres hacer porque por lo que veo ya lo estás haciendo. Al hacer el new del diágolo, en en constructor ya le estás pasando datos de MainActivity. Solo te queda definir variables miembro de la clase AlarmaDialogo para guardar esos valores que le envías en el constructor. Y dentro del constructor guardas los datos recibidos en las variables miembro. Otra opción es implementar funciones set y llamarlas después de hacer el new del diálogo y antes de hacer el show.

Comment: @SuperG280 efectivamente cuando llamo al dialogo le paso 3 variables pero luego no tengo acceso a ellas en el dialog.Me explico,le paso las 3 variables,perfecto,pero en la siguiente linea tengo el show del dialogo y de ahi se va al onCreate del dialogo y cuando intento pasarle las variables que vienen del activity nada,no puedo acceder a ellas y logicamente me sale vacio.La opcion que me has dado ¿Como seria? Te lo agradeceria mucho.Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale. Despues de leer tus comentarios ya entiendo lo que quieres hacer. Lo tienes medio hecho pero te falta esto:

La definición del constructor está correcta:

```
public AlarmaDialogo( Context context,String totales, Integer sumaDeAlarmas) {
    super(context);

}
```

Pero tienes que guardar los datos que recibes en algún lado, así que puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Defines tantas variables en la clase AlarmaDialogo como parámetros necesites pasar en el constructor. En tu caso:

```
public class AlarmaDialogo extends Dialog implements
    android.view.View.OnClickListener {

private String Totales;
private Integer SumaDeAlarmas;
...

public AlarmaDialogo( Context context,String totales, Integer sumaDeAlarmas) {
        super(context);
        Totales = totales;
        SumaDeAlarmas = sumaDeAlarmas;
}
```

Y entonces, cuando desde MainActivity llames al constructor y le pases totales y sumaDeAlarmas, guardará sus valores en las variables miembro de la clase AlarmaDialogo que hemos creado. Cuando después llames al show, Android llamará a OnCreate de AlarmaDialogo y ahí podrás usar las variables Totales y SumaDeAlarmas, que son miembros de la clase y tendrán posicionados los valores recibidos en el constructor.

No puedes definir un objeto de la clase MainActivity dentro del Diálogo para obtener sus datos, sino que es MainActivity el que le pasa los datos que necesite el diálogo en el constructor. Si necesitas más parámetros además de totales y sumaDeAlarmas, pues incluyes más variables miembro y le pasas más parámetros en el constructor.

Suerte!

Comment: Lo primero agradecerte la respuesta y efectivamente lo tenia e mis ojos pero no lo sacaba jejeje.El problema que tengo es que cuando entra al show del dialogo y va al OnCreate algo pasa que las variables a las cuales les di valor en el constructor se ponen a Null y no entiendo por que...Quizas el onCreate pasa a Null todo?Lo tengo casi casi pero me falla eso.

Comment: nada,disculpame,fallo mio que estoy ya que no se ni lo que hago jejeje.Si que me funciona,perfectamente.Muchas muchas muchas gracias!